# Signed client certificate not accepted by websocket server

Tags: ssl, certificate, python, websocket

Want to set up authentication in a python websocket server which builds up its ssl context like:

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ctx.load_cert_chain('certificates/server_cert.pem', 'certificates/server_key.pem')
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ctx.load_verify_locations('certificates/bob_cert.pem')
```

Following the example in [here](https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326) (only for the creation of certificates) I created three keypairs and certificates, one for the websocket server and two client certs. As stated in the example I signed alice's cert with the server cert and bob's cert is self-signed.

If I now connect via bob's cert and set `verify_locations` in the server as above, bob magically gets into the server (which doesn't do more then echo back what you sent).
But if I connect via alice's cert (signed by server cert) I do not get accepted - getting a `ConnectionResetError`, the parameter `verify_locations` in the above code is then of course set to accept *alice_cert.pem*. For completion, below you find the code for ssl context creation of the client side (here for bob):

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ctx.check_hostname = True
ctx.load_verify_locations('certificates/server_cert.pem')
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ctx.load_cert_chain('certificates/bob_cert.pem', 'certificates/bob_key.pem')
```

What am I doing wrong or where did I misunderstand the tutorial I followed (link above), how can the unrelated (to the server cert) self-signed certificate used by bob (ISSUER CN=bob, SUBJ CN=bob) get access whereas alice cert which is signed by the server cert (ISSUER CN=localhost, SUBJ CN=alice) does get rejected?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, issue found. As the [example](https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326) stated, people should put the *server_cert.pem* in `load_verify_locations` in the websocket server ssl context. Works now as expected when doing so.. Alice gets in, Bob does not.